# Find the Area Under the Given Curve $y = 8 cos\ (πx), y = 8x^2 − 2$

Tags: calculus

Find the Area Under the Given Curve $y = 8 \ cos (πx),    y = 8x^2 − 2$

[image]

Can I use this integral to find the area under the curve? $\int^{1.5}_{-1.5}((8x^2)8\ cos(\pi \ x))dx$

Comment: No. The integral you are using is wrong. So is the graph.

Answer (score 3):

Your graph of $8x^2-2$ is off; you have instead plotted $8x^2$.

If you are indeed trying to compute the area *between* the curves, then the integral in question should be

$$
\int_{x=x_1}^{x_2} [f(x)-g(x)] \, dx
$$

where $f(x) = 8 \cos \pi x$ is the "upper" function, and $g(x) = 8x^2-2$ is the lower function, and $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the two $x$-values for which $f(x) = g(x)$.  If you plot the two functions accurately, you should be able to obtain these two values by inspection.

Comment: How is it off? I  graphed it with Wolfalpha

Comment: Should my integral look like this $\int^{1.5}_{-1.5}((8cos(\pi \ x)-8x^2-2)dx$?

Comment: The first sentence of my answer explains how your plot is off. ¶ Your integral is not quite correct: In the first place, your limits of integration are wrong; the two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are not equal at $x = \pm 1.5$.  In the second place, you should have $8 \cos \pi x - (8x^2-2)$ in the integrand, not $8 \cos \pi x - 8x^2-2$.  (It is otherwise correct.) ¶ P.S.  You should typeset $\cos \pi x$ as "\cos \pi x" for better appearance.

Comment: So are the bounds 1/2 and -1/2?

Comment: Well, the $-1/2$ as the lower bound and $1/2$ as the upper, but yeah.

Comment: My answer is $\frac{16}{\pi}+\frac{8}{3}$ Am I right?

Comment: Change that to $\frac{16}{\pi}+\frac{4}{3}$

Comment: @Martin- What should my graph look like? http://www.webassign.net/waplots/2/c/4c6a4f157fbc0213eb1607e843f7e2.gif or http://www.webassign.net/waplots/9/2/92df5c80483f7578b721520598f9b7.gif or

Comment: @Cetshwayo the first one.